# Convert a list of dictionaries into pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of dictionaries looks like the following. Every dictionary is a list item.

```
my_list= [{"_id":1,"name":"xxx"},
    {"_id":2,"name":"yyy"},
    {"_id":3,"_name":"zzz"}]
```

I am trying to convert the list into a pyspark dataframe, with every dictionary being a row.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(my_list, StringType())

df.show()
```

My ideal result is the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                    dic|
+-----------------------------------------+
|{"_id":1,"name":"xxx"}|
|{"_id":2,"name":"yyy"}|
|{"_id":3,"_name":"zzz"}|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

But I got the error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 25.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 25.0 (TID 95, 10.0.16.11, executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Spark might have difficulty in casting the Python dictionaries to strings. You can convert the dictionaries to strings before creating a dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([str(i) for i in my_list], StringType())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the dicts into strings before creating dataframe. However, I'd suggest you not to store values as *stringfied* dicts. It wouldn't be easy to parse them for further transformations later. Use JSON strings instead :

```
import json

df = spark.createDataFrame([[json.dumps(d)] for d in my_list], ["dict"])

df.show(truncate=False)

#+--------------------------+
#|dict                      |
#+--------------------------+
#|{"_id": 1, "name": "xxx"} |
#|{"_id": 2, "name": "yyy"} |
#|{"_id": 3, "_name": "zzz"}|
#+--------------------------+
```